Sheets forumla for min from vlookup of row values
I am trying to find the minimum value after a vlookup from a row of values and return the vlookup value itself instead of the minimum. This is to find where pinch points on a computer network are located but could also be used to find where pinch points within a plumbing system or similair system is. In the attached picture everthing is trying to take the most direct path to the internet cloud in the top left, the number in the box indicates the capacity of a link between devices. As an example the path taken from device 12 to the INTERNET would be 12>11>9>10>1>INTERNET with the pinch point located between device 11 and device 9.  The table below also shows the same information presented in the picture in tabular format and I am trying to find a formula for the "Pinch Point Calculated on overhead" column to calculate on a much larger scale.



Name
fed by
fed by2
fed by3
fed by4
fed by5
fed by6
fed by7
fed by8
Link capacity (Mbps)
max utilization (Mbps)
percentage of utilization
Available overhead in Mbps
Priority Higher is more important
Pinch point calculated on overhead




TOWER 1








10000.0
1.0
0.0%
9999
0
Self


TOWER 2
TOWER 1







5000.0
1.0
0.0%
4999
0
Self


TOWER 3
TOWER 2
TOWER 1






1000.0
1.0
0.1%
999
0
Self


TOWER 4
TOWER 2
TOWER 1






1000.0
1.0
0.1%
999
0
Self


TOWER 5
TOWER 2
TOWER 1






1000.0
1.0
0.1%
999
0
Self


TOWER 6
TOWER 7
TOWER 8
TOWER 9
TOWER 10
TOWER 1



500.0
1.0
0.2%
499
0
Tower 8


TOWER 7
TOWER 8
TOWER 9
TOWER 10
TOWER 1




500.0
1.0
0.2%
499
0
Tower 8


TOWER 8
TOWER 9
TOWER 10
TOWER 1





250.0
1.0
0.4%
249
0
Self


TOWER 9
TOWER 10
TOWER 1






1000.0
1.0
0.1%
999
0
Self


TOWER 10
TOWER 1







5000.0
1.0
0.0%
4999
0
Self


TOWER 11
TOWER 9
TOWER 10
TOWER 1





500.0
1.0
0.2%
499
0
Self


TOWER 12
TOWER 11
TOWER 9
TOWER 10
TOWER 1




1000.0
1.0
0.1%
999
0
Tower 11


TOWER 13
TOWER 10
TOWER 1






2500.0
1.0
0.0%
2499
0
Self


TOWER 14
TOWER 13
TOWER 10
TOWER 1





1000.0
1.0
0.1%
999
0
Self


TOWER 15
TOWER 14
TOWER 13
TOWER 10
TOWER 1




500.0
1.0
0.2%
499
0
Self


TOWER 16
TOWER 15
TOWER 14
TOWER 13
TOWER 10
TOWER 1



500.0
1.0
0.2%
499
0
Self


TOWER 17
TOWER 15
TOWER 14
TOWER 13
TOWER 10
TOWER 1



1000.0
1.0
0.1%
999
0
Tower 15



I have tried to find a way to do something like a python dict and find the tower with the least from the list but I can not think of a way to do that in excel or sheets.

Excel and Google Sheets are two separate products, which have differences in syntax and functionality between them. You're using one or the other. If you're using both, you need to post two different questions. Please remove the content and tag for the product you're not specifically asking about here.

I am using sheets but have access to either excel or sheets so I included both tags

Don't do that. If your data is in Sheets, then your question is about that platform. Using both wastes the time of people who write an answer only to find out it doesn't work on the platform you're using. It also wastes the time of future readers who are searching to find a solution to a problem and have to read the question to find out which one the answer was actually written to use. Tags have relevance and meaning here, and tag spamming is a very quick way to get your question closed and/or downvoted.

There's also the issue of having two different people answer, one that works in Excel and the other in Sheets. Both are correct for their platform, but you can only accept one as being the solution to your problem. Which one do you reward for their work with that accept, and which one do you punish by not giving it to them instead?

Can you maybe provide the stepwise backend logic on how this pinch point is calculated citing an example row from your test data?!

In google sheets I have modified an answer that was provided yesterday for office365 excel.
Regarding logic flowing looking at Tower 6
it is fed by 7>8>9>10>1>Internet in that order

6>7 has a 500 Mbps capacity
7>8 has a 500 Mbps capacity
8>9 has a 250
Mbps Capacity
9>10 has a 1000 Mbps capacity
10>1 has a 5000 Mbps
capacity
1>Internet has a 10000 Mbps capacity

Therefore traffic passing to tower 6 is limited by tower 8>9 link


=ArrayFormula(LET(t,BYROW(A$2:I$18,LAMBDA(x,REDUCE("",x,LAMBDA(z,y,IF(AND(y<>"",XLOOKUP(y,A:A,M:M,99999999,0)<XLOOKUP(z,A:A,M:M,99999999,0)),y,z))))),IF(t=$A$2:$A$18,"Self",t)))



